# POST request from React to Node.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I don't know why this happens.

When I'm making a request to my server in Node.js and when it's GET then I can get a response. It looks like that:

```
fetch(config.apiUsersURL, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    credentials: "same-origin",
    mode: 'no-cors'
})
  .then(res => this.setState({
    isConected: true
  }))
  .catch(error => error);
```

When I'm requesting to the same url but with POST I'm getting nothing. Am I missing something?

```
const ObjToSend = { isReady: true };
fetch( config.apiUsersURL, {  
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',  
    body: JSON.stringify(ObjToSend),
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    credentials: "same-origin",
    mode: 'no-cors',
})
.then(res => res.json()) 
.then(r => this.setState({ questions: r }))
```

My endpoint looks like that:

```
let randomProblem2;
router.post('/', (req, resp) => {
  resp.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  resp.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type')
  console.log("this shows if yes was clicked", req.body)
  if(req.body.isReady){ //when clicked
    randomProblem2 = problemManager.getRandomProblem();
    randomize(randomProblem2, resp);
  } 
})

function randomize(randomProblem2, resp){
  resp.json({
    randomProblem : randomProblem2
  }
  )}
```

Comment: Could you show us the node.js endpoint?

Comment: I updated the question, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the mode you are using is `no-cors`, you cannot use javascript to access the response

Quoted below from MDN:

> no-cors — Prevents the method from being anything other than HEAD, GET
>   or POST, and the headers from being anything other than simple
>   headers. If any ServiceWorkers intercept these requests, they may not
>   add or override any headers except for those that are simple headers.
>   In addition, JavaScript may not access any properties of the resulting
>   Response. This ensures that ServiceWorkers do not affect the semantics
>   of the Web and prevents security and privacy issues arising from
>   leaking data across domains.

Kindly check the MDN link below for the rest of mode options
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode

Comment: Ok, I get it, but when I'm trying not to use cors console says I need to use no-cors mode ;)

Comment: You have to add "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" , "Access-Control-Allow-Headers"  and "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" in your response header while sending response from Node. So follow this link : https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html . It will be of help.

Comment: Sorry i missed the endpoint portion in your answer. I guess it the "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" which is causing the issue. Can you kindly add that to the response as well. Do you mind sharing the screenshot of the request and response from the network tab in inspector.